# Kafka exactly once messaging test with "consume-transform-produce" Integration test

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am writing testcase to test the my application's consume-transform-produce loop of the Kafka. So effectively I am consuming from a sourceTopic-processing-sendMessage to Destination topic. I am writing these testcases to prove the exactly once messaging with Kafka as I will add other failure cases later.

Here is my configuration:

```
private Map<String, Object> consConfigProps(boolean txnEnabled) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(
            KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps(AB_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID, "false", kafkaBroker));
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, AB_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}

private Map<String, Object> prodConfigProps(boolean txnEnabled) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(kafkaBroker));
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "client-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "3");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG,
                "prod-txn-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return props;
}

public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, NormalUser> fetchContainer() {
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(ABTOPIC, XYTOPIC, PATOPIC);
    containerProperties.setGroupId("groupId-10001");
    containerProperties.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
    containerProperties.setSyncCommits(true);
    containerProperties.setSyncCommitTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
    containerProperties.setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager());
    KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, NormalUser> kafkaMessageListContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(
            consumerFactory(), containerProperties);
    kafkaMessageListContainer.setupMessageListener(new AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, NormalUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, NormalUser> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
            log.debug("test-listener received message='{}'", record.toString());
            records.add(record);
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
    });
    return kafkaMessageListContainer;
}

    @Test
    public void testProducerABSuccess() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        NormalUser userObj = new NormalUser(ABTypeGood,
                Double.valueOf(Math.random() * 10000).longValue(),
                "Blah" + String.valueOf(Math.random() * 10));
        sendMessage(XYTOPIC, "AB-id", userObj);
        try {
            ConsumerRecords<String, NormalUser> records;
            parserConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(XYTOPIC));
            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> currentOffsets = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            // Check for messages
            parserProducer.beginTransaction();
            records = parserConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
            assertThat(1).isEqualTo(records.count()); // --> this asserts passes like 50% of the time. 
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, NormalUser> record : records) {
                assertEquals(record.key(), "AB-id");
                assertEquals(record.value(), userObj);
                currentOffsets.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                        new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset()));
            }
            parserProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, NormalUser>(ABTOPIC, "AB-id", userObj));
            parserProducer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(currentOffsets, AB_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID);
            parserProducer.commitTransaction();
        } catch (ProducerFencedException | OutOfOrderSequenceException | AuthorizationException e) {
            parserProducer.close();
        } catch (final KafkaException e) {
            parserProducer.abortTransaction();
        }
        ConsumerRecords<String, NormalUser> records;
        loadConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(ABTOPIC));
        records = loadConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
        assertThat(1).isEqualTo(records.count()); //--> this assert fails all the time. 
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, NormalUser> record : records) {
            assertEquals(record.key(), "AB-id");
            assertEquals(record.value(), userObj);
        }
    }
```

My issue is that the above testcase "testProducerABSuccess" is not consistent and the asserts fails sometimes and sometimes they pass. I have not been able to figure out why they are so inconsistent. What is wrong with the above.

Edits: 16-12:

1. Tested with consumerconfig.Auto_Offset_Reset_config-earliest no change. The first assert passes like 70% of the time. The second assert fails all the time (0% pass rate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which assertion fails? If it's `assertThat(1).isEqualTo(records.count());`, it's probably because you are setting `auto.offset.reset` to `latest`. It needs to be `earliest` to avoid a race condition whereby the record is sent before the consumer is assigned the partitition(s).

Comment: I tested with "consumerconfig.Auto_Offset_Reset_config=earliest". Now the first assert passes like 70% of the time more or less same as earlier. The second assert fails all the time (0% pass rate). 2nd assert failure logs: 
 
 org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatResponseHandler: [Consumer clientId=consumer-ebs-10001-1, groupId=ebs-10001] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing. this goes on forever.

Comment: You should put the consumers in different groups; you should also close the first consumer. Also, consider using `assign()` instead of `subscribe()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, you made my day. Solution did the following. Created separate group for each consumer. 2. producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction mapped to the same consumergroup, 3. assigned partition to consumer and producer also used partitions to send messaged for finer control for assertion. Test cases are passing. Cheers.